# How to import Quickbooks sales transactions in laravel

Tags: laravel, import, quickbooks

How can i import this sales data into laravel?
[This is the data  i want to import in laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL2Ai.png)

I'll try php sdk to resolve this but I am confused about the data I receive it returns null

`$transactions = $dataService->Query("SELECT * FROM Transaction");`

i have this query but i didn't get any data

Comment: have you checked https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/transactionlist

Comment: Yes can you give me some steps about this article?